# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source'

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-dl

I recently decided to create a Discord bot that plays MP3 audio, I was unable to find a solution.

Initially, the error was this:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: FFmpeg was not found, but we found a fix by writing next to FILE NAME.MP3, executable =
```

The error above came out. Can you help me? Thanks.

Code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import json
import math
import os

@client.command()
async def pmartina(ctx):
    voicechannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='Musica')
    vc = await voicechannel.connect()
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(excutable="martina.mp3"), print('done'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio...` line, you're ussing FFmpeg, but you never imported it.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import json
import math
import os
import ffmpeg

@client.command()
async def pmartina(ctx):
    voicechannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='Musica')
    vc = await voicechannel.connect()
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(excutable="martina.mp3"), print('done'))
```

Also, make sure to [download ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) and set up the path correctly. There are many videos online to help you do this correctly, such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1AtmY-RMyQ) one for Windows and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1o6MWnmwpY) one for MacOS. If you want a more detailed walkthrough to make a music bot, refer to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ml-5tXRmmFk&t=700s).